# Do WCF Services Expose Properties?

Tags: c#, wcf

In the interface required to implement a WCF service, I declare the main class with the `[ServiceContract()]` attribute and any exposed method with `[OperationContract()]`.

How can i expose public properties? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. That's not how it works. Methods only.

Comment: Indeed. Just to expand (without the need for another answer) - it is an RPC stack - not a remoting stack. If you want properties, return an object from a method, and look at the properties of the object at the client.

Comment: I'll agree with Marc, but clarify: it's not WCF that's the RPC stack; it's SOAP+WSDL standards that are. All they can describe is operations, sent in a message. There's not even the concept of an instance, so what would you be getting properties _from_?

Answer (score 22):

Since the *get* portion of a property is a method, this will technically work but, as mentioned in previous answers/comments, this may not be advisable; just posting it here for general knowledge.

**Service Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    string Name
    {
        [OperationContract]
        get;
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Steve"; }
    }
}
```

**To access from your client code:**

```
var client = new Service1Client();
var name = client.get_Name();
```

Comment: +1.  However, viewers be warned against the interpretation _"OK, so I guess I'll just change my properties into Java style GetXxx + SetXxx method pairs, and that will be more advisable."_  No, that would rather be pointless.  After you rule out performance concerns of which either syntax smells equally, feel free to expose your property accessors.

Answer (score 4):

Properties are an object oriented aspect of component interfaces. WCF is about **services**, where you have to think about and design the sequence of interactions between your components.

Object orientation does not scale well to distributed scenarios (where your code executes on multiple servers or even in multiple processes) due to the cost of roundtrips, potentially expensive state management, and versioning challenges. However, OO is still a good way of designing the internals of services, especially if they are complex.

Answer (score 4):

You can expose properties but u will have to use `[DataContract]` attribute and can declare property as `[DataMember]` attribute for properties.

Answer (score 2):

PLEASE PLEASE don't expose Properties as a web method.. This will not work in HTTPS. I had BIG time identifying and fixing this issue.  The best way is to write a concrete method to return in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps things have changed since this question was initially asked, but on .NET 4.8 you can expose properties.

The interface declaration looks like this.

```
    string CapturePath 
    {
        [OperationContract]
        get;
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        set; 
    }
```

The caller uses it just like any property, such as:

```
            _captureThing.CapturePath = "test";
            LogMessage(_captureThing.CapturePath);
```