# Adding public class to [operationcontract] in WCF to expose to the client?

Tags: c#, wcf

Can I call a public class from service to [operationcontract] in WCF to expose to the client? Here is my code:

Service.svc.cs

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public class UserRights
    {
        public static bool _canEdit;
    }
}
```

And this is for my
IService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "UserRightsContract")]
    public class UserRights;
}
```

Update

I want to expose public class `UserRights` to the client through WCF. I'm thinking if possible to create a method to expose class to the client?

Comment: Do you mean, can you call that class method from a different class and not through WCF? Actually your question is confusing , you might consider rewording it

Comment: Sorry, @Saruman. what I mean is I want to expose `public class UserRights` to the client through WCF. I'm thinking if possible to create a method to expose class to the client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do WCF Services Expose Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824268/do-wcf-services-expose-properties)

Comment: Your code makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to expose the `UserRights` Class is to return it in a Method Call

Decorate your class with `DataContract`

```
[DataContract]
public class UserRights
{
    [DataMember]
    public static bool _canEdit;
}
```

Add the method to your Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Service : IService
{
   ...

    [OperationContract]
    UserRights GetUserRights();
}
```

Implement it in your Service

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public UserRights GetUserRights()
    {
        return new UserRights();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.
How to create Method to expose Class's?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I call a public class from service to [operationcontract] in WCF
>   to expose to the client?

You can't. You can only expose methods only using WCF.

What you have written in your interface is also not correct. You don't need to write public, by default everything is public.

If you want to expose the instance of the class you can do something like.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "UserRightsContract")]
    UserRights GetUserRights();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public UserRights GetUserRights()
    {
        UserRights userRights = new UserRights();
        //Set other properties.
        return userRights;
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class UserRights
{
    [DataMember]
    public static bool _canEdit;
}
```